# write and update key to ini file c#

Tags: c#

i want write some setting to ini file with this code that search to find key and update it and if can't find the key add it to file .  but it show this error : 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
i try this code :

```
    internal class IniData
    {
        public string Key;
        public string Value;
    }

    internal class IniSection : Dictionary<string, IniData>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    internal class IniFile : Dictionary<string, IniSection>
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class IniManager
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, IniFile> IniFiles;
        static IniManager()
        {
            IniFiles = new Dictionary<string, IniFile>();
        }

        public static void WriteIni(string fileName, string section, string key, string value)
        {
            /* Check if ini file exists in the ini collection */
            var fileKey = fileName.ToLower();
            if (!IniFiles.ContainsKey(fileKey))
            {
                if (!ImportIni(fileKey))
                {
                    /* Add a new blank file */
                    var ini = new IniFile { Path = fileName };
                    IniFiles.Add(fileKey, ini);
                }
            }
            /* Find section */
            if (IniFiles[fileKey].ContainsKey(section.ToLower()))
            {
                /* Find key, if exists replace it */
                if (IniFiles[fileKey][section.ToLower()].ContainsKey(key.ToLower()))
                {
                    IniFiles[fileKey][section.ToLower()][key.ToLower()].Value = value;
                    return;
                }
                var data = new IniData { Key = key, Value = value };
                IniFiles[fileKey][section.ToLower()].Add(key.ToLower(), data);
            }
            else
            {
                /* Create new ini section */
                var sec = new IniSection { Name = section };
                var data = new IniData { Key = key, Value = value };
                sec.Add(key.ToLower(), data);
                IniFiles[fileKey].Add(section.ToLower(), sec);
            }
        }
        private static bool ImportIni(string fileName)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileName)) { return false; }
            string[] data;
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        data = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { return false; }
            if (data.Length == 0) { return false; }
            var file = new IniFile { Path = fileName };
            var section = new IniSection();
            foreach (var s in data)
            {
                if (s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]"))
                {
                    /* Section header */
                    if (section.Count > 0)
                    {
                        /* Add current section */
                        file.Add(section.Name.ToLower(), section);
                    }
                    section = new IniSection { Name = s.Replace("[", null).Replace("]", null) };
                    continue;
                }
                /* Using current section, parse ini keys/values */
                var iniData = ParseIni(s);
                section.Add(iniData.Key.ToLower(), iniData);
            }
            if (section.Count > 0)
            {
                /* Add current section */
  //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Erorr : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                file.Add(section.Name.ToLower(), section);
            }
            IniFiles.Add(fileName, file);
            return true;
        }
        private static IniData ParseIni(string s)
        {
            var parts = s.Split('=');
            return new IniData { Key = parts[0].Trim(), Value = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1].Trim() : string.Empty };
        }
    }
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IniManager.WriteIni("seting.ini", "Sec", "key", "value");

    }
```

Comment: What line does this occur on?

Comment: There are ten million questions on SO about `NullReferenceException`. Please read them, try to understand what happens, debug your program and find the answer yourself. Hint: it's about `Section.Name`.

Comment: Using an INI file seems a little old fashioned.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using [GetPrivateProfileString](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPrivateProfileString.html) and [WritePrivateProfileString](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WritePrivateProfileString.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing this yourself you should just use the API functions that Windows provide. Of course, if you need to run this on Mono or other platforms than Windows, you need to go back to a pure .NET implementation, but even so I would probably go look for an existing implementation instead of creating that wheel yourself.

Anywhere, here's the API functions:

- [GetPrivateProfileString](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPrivateProfileString.html)
- [WritePrivateProfileString](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WritePrivateProfileString.html)

Here's an example [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that uses them:

(hit F4 and paste the following two lines into the additional namespace tab):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices
System.ComponentModel
```

Then try this program:

```
void Main()
{
    var ini = new IniFile(@"d:\temp\test.ini");
    ini.WriteValue("Section", "Key", "Value");
    ini.ReadValue("Section", "Key").Dump();

    ini["Main", "Key2"] = "Test";
    ini["Main", "Key2"].Dump();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint GetPrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName,string lpDefault, StringBuilder lpReturnedString, uint nSize,string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpString, string lpFileName);

public class IniFile
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 1024;

    private readonly string _FilePath;

    public IniFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (filePath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath");

        _FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public string this[string section, string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return ReadValue(section, key);
        }

        set
        {
            WriteValue(section, key, value);
        }
    }

    public string ReadValue(string section, string key, string defaultValue = null)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder(MAX_SIZE);
        if (GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, defaultValue ?? string.Empty, result, (uint)result.Capacity, _FilePath) > 0)
            return result.ToString();

        throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    public void WriteValue(string section, string key, string value)
    {
        if (!WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, _FilePath))
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that if the file starts with a key and not with a section, the `foreach` doesn't match the `if (s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]"))` at all and so the `Section.Name` is never set, thus it is `null` when called in `file.Add(section.Name.ToLower(), section);`

BTW: your code seems quite buggy, try to redesign it at least in the main `foreach` of `ImportIni`